# Text area with intellisense functionality in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, intellisense

I have **text area** and I want to get **IntelliSense functionality** for it (as IntelliSense in VS2010) and when user types in it, I want to display related keywords and let the user select from the results and use any number of times.

Note:  Auto-complete box is not satisfying my requirement.

Comment: Hi all.....I managed to get my requirement..if any one needs the code i can help.....

Comment: Please post your answer and accept it so the question is removed from the unanswered list.

Comment: You should really post the answer to your question and accept it.

Comment: Hello. Please, post somewhere your solution.